# how to display date from and date to according to the selected

Tags: php, laravel

[image: view]

my view

```
<tr>
     <th colspan="4" class="text-center"> {{Carbon\Carbon::parse(request()->query('filter_date'))->format('d F') }}</th>
     <th colspan="2" class="text-center">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(request()->query('end_date'))->format('d F') }}</th>                                  
 </tr>
```

how to display from date to date as selected, for example I choose from the 1st to the 5th, so it will appear from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th but now I only manage to display the beginning and end of only the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) to get the range from two dates.  Here, I am providing you with an example, so you can get the idea.

```
    $requestFromDate = '02/25/2022';
    $requestToDate = '03/03/2022';
    $fromDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($requestFromDate)->format('Y-m-d');
    $toDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($requestToDate)->format('Y-m-d');

    $dateRangePeriod = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($fromDate, $toDate);
    $dateRange = [];
    foreach ($dateRangePeriod as $key => $date) {
        $dateRange[] = $date->format('d  F');
    }

    return $dateRange;
```

The output:

```
[
   "25 February",
   "26 February",
   "27 February",
   "28 February",
   "01 March",
   "02 March",
   "03 March"
]
```